Can a Proxy trap assignment to a variable referring to it?
Consider the following Proxy object:
let proxy = new Proxy({}, handler);

If I perform the following assignment, the proxy instance will be overwriten, losing the trap handlers:
proxy = {};

Alright, but if I perform the assignment using Object.assign, it keeps being the same instance (retaining the trap handlers):
Object.assign({}, proxy);

But doing it this way, none of the proxy traps get triggered.
Is it possible to make the proxy trap any of those assignment methods (using either = or Object.assign?

Did you mean Object.assign(proxy, {})?

No, I need to "merge" an object's properties to the proxy object, all at once. Either triggering defineProperty or set or some other trap, but in a way that I get all "merged" properties at once, without triggering the traps multiple times.

"I need to "merge" an object's properties to the proxy object" - well that's why I would have expected you use the proxy as the target of the Object.assign call. What  Object.assign({}, proxy) is doing is to merge all of the proxy object's properties into the new empty object.

Oh god you're right, Object.assign does trigger the traps, multiple times in fact, guess I better delete the question haha!

No, it is not possible to trap a reassignment of the variable holding the proxy.
As for using Object.assign with a proxy, that will usually trigger some traps, either set (for properties being copied from the source to the proxy target) or ownKeys (if the proxy is used as a source). Only if you assign nothing to the proxy (Object.assign(proxy) or Object.assign(proxy, {})), then nothing happens.
There is no syntax (with a single respective trap) to modify the proxy with multiple property updates. What you may actually be looking for is a normal method, such as proxy.reset({}).

I was totally mistaken when I said that Object.assign didn't trigger any traps, it was just using it the worng way, id does trigger the traps, one time for each merged property. I'll try to solve my problem some other way.

What does proxy.reset({}) actually do? I tried it but it seems like it doesn't exist?

@PedroHenrique It's not a standard method. But if you're looking for "a way that I get all "merged" properties at once, without triggering the traps multiple times", you should just go the OOP way and have your object offer a method (like reset) to call for that.
